# Displaying a directed graph from edge set using pydot

Tags: python, graph, networkx, pydot

I want to create a directed graph using `pydot` and I have a ready-made edge set as well. The type of edge set can be a list or a tuple which is no matter, because I can construct the set of edge according to my requirement in advance, just like `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,2)]` or `((1,2),(2,3),(3,2))`.

I initialize a `pydot` object `g` as follows :

```
g = pydot.Dot()
g.set_type('digraph')
```

After that, I find there has not a function likes `add_edge_from`, only has a `add_edge` function for `g`. Is it means I must generate edge one by one??

Perhaps I could create graph from edge set by following ways at the beginning.

```
g=pydot.graph_from_edges(edge_set)
```

But I find it will produce a undirected graph:(

By the way, I try to realize the graph using `networkx` and success. However, its garish and circuitous showing presentation mode, which attach more importance to edge other than node (Sorry it is just my opinion, and of course you may disagree with it), is not accord with I want in this case now.

So is anyone have any ideas or advises for me? Is there off-the-shelf method I can use? Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph([(1,2),(2,3),(3,2)])

In [3]: from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot

In [4]: write_dot(G,'file.dot')

In [5]: !dot -Tpng file.dot >file.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you in advance. Unfortunately, I cannot find out the meaning of In[5] (can not be executed) and In[4] gives me ImportError: No module named pydotplus. Could you help me make clear? By the way, I use Pycharm as IDE in python 2.7.

Comment: Then I have Spyder to run the code you give above. The ImportError no longer exists now. But the console still says the SyntaxError: invalid syntax in In[5]:(

Comment: It's IPython output.  You want just the part after the colon (:).  Line 4 produces a dot file which you can render in the usual way with graphviz.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why the ImportError exists again,says No module named pydotplus. Do you know how to install pydotplus via conda? I try to google it but failed to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

@chen-xu, you are on the right track with creating a digraph object.  What you have to do to get it to be a directed graph is to create node objects using pydot.Node(), and then create an edge object where you specify the source and destination nodes, and then add this edge object to your graph.  
Find an example below:

```
import pydot                                                                                                                                                                
stackoverflow_graph = pydot.Dot("stackoverflow_graph", graph_type="digraph", bgcolor="white")                                                                               
child_node = pydot.Node(name='Childish Node')                                                                                                                               
parent_node = pydot.Node(name='Grownup Node')                                                                                                                               
directed_edge = pydot.Edge(src=parent_node, dst=child_node, label="Node, I am your father!")                                                                                
stackoverflow_graph.add_edge(directed_edge)                                                                                                                                 
stackoverflow_graph.write_jpeg('./stackoverflow_graph.jpg')
```

[image: Directed graph with misdirected humor.]